# What is the correct form and why: The crocodile was alive for millions of years or the crocodile is alive for millions of years

Tags: tenses

I'm pretty sure that the correct form is "was alive for million of years" but I need to know the grammatical explanation for it.

Comment: "has been alive for million of years" (grammatical, but Creationists would say inaccurate).

Comment: "The crocodile has existed for millions of years." *Nothing* has been alive for millions of years.

Comment: Neither is correct. "*The crocodile* ***was alive for***.... *years*" means that the crocodile species is *now* dead, or no longer in existence. "*The crocodile* ***is alive for*** ... years*" is ungrammatical. The Present Perfect and the PP Continuous tense are normally used to express duration. If I wanted to talk about the longevity of a species I'd say: *The crocodile* ***is believed to be*** *X million years old*

Answer (score 2):

**Is alive for million of years** - Sounds very confusing

**was alive for million of years** - Sounds like it was alive, but no longer is that the case. This is better but still not entirely correct by my ear.

I'd go with either:

**Has existed for millions of years**

or

**Has lived for millions of years** - While this might not be grammatically perfect, it is a common phrasing.